# How to kill the processes when no root permission and nproc limit exceeded?

Tags: linux, process, non-root-user, limit, ulimit

So, a user had exceeded her `nproc` limit. Due to this, both SSH and `su` are unable to login as the target user. However, there is no accessible shell which is owned by the user. How can this be solved without root permission?

Thanks

Comment: User can run `kill <pid>` or `pkill <process name>` on processes that was run by her to send a SIGTERM ( terminate) signal. If process refuses to terminate, `-9` flag would forcefully shutdown a process. Though without a root permission user can't kill system processes or processes that was started by other users.

Comment: @ddnomad please note that `nproc` limit has exceeded - new process can't be started not even `kill`.

Comment: I have posted my solution. However, still looking for a better way as my way requires you have to other user's credential.

Comment: `kill` is a `bash` builtin, so I think some situations would allow you to run it even after exceeding this limit. As a last ditch effort, you could always `exec kill -9 pid`, but that kills your shell, too

Comment: @Fox Due to this, we can't do both SSH and `su`... I should have mentioned it. The problem is modified to reflect this. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Wait, `nproc` is a per-user limit — anyone with `su` access can kill that user's processes, as can the original user. Are these processes that are running without a controlling shell after the user has logged off?

Comment: @Fox Yes, actually it was caused by a fork bomb with parent process `init`. When trying to use other shell to `su`to the target user, it said `Resource temporarily unavailable`. By `su`, I actually meant `su TARGET_USER` instead of getting root permission as the question describes a solution where root permission is unable to obtain(without rootkits of course)

Answer (score 2):

As I see nproc and "ulimit" tag, I'll add 2 points to this ulimit mecanism:

I'd expect your sysadmin to have put a soft-limit a bit lower than the hard-limit, exactly to avoid the case you're on. That way, you can increase your soft-value to launch `su` from another account and use that to do a kill.

Also, keep in mind that the ulimits are set by PAM (`grep -r pam_limits.so /etc/pam.d/`), so if you have an authentication method / program that doesn't use this PAM module, you can avoid this ulimit and generate a kill.

Aside from these 2 solutions that require an action before the issue arise, there's indeed no way to send a signal to an existing program without having the correct access (same user, root, setuid or capability `CAP_KILL`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have other user's credential and the target user's credential can be used to change the file system somehow, you may compile the following program, set the s bit and use other user's credential to execute it.

NOTE: the executable must be owned by the target user in order to be able to `seteuid` to the target user's `uid`.

The first argument of the program is the target user's `uid`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    if(seteuid(atoi(argv[1])) != 0) {
        printf("seteuid failed... %d", errno);
    }
    if(kill(-1, SIGTERM) != 0) {
    printf("kill failed...%d", errno);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I doubt this way would work as other non-root user has no permission to kill processes of a former user. Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, this was used to solve the mess that was going on. It works because of the s bit. By using the s bit, the program will be able to seteuid to the target user id. Maybe I should state it more clearly that the file must be owned by the target user.

Comment: Hm, then it's an interesting thing. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: ddnomad, You are welcome! Still looking for a better solution though since this requires you to have other user's credential. Thanks ddnomad!

Comment: I consulted relative who is quite good in sysadmin stuff and he said there is no other way (sadly)

Answer (score 0):

If `nproc` has been reached, the kernel isn't going to allow any other processes to run with that user's credentials, as you learned. This means no remote session over SSH, no `su` or `sudo`, not even a program setuid to their account.

That leaves you with either root, or the user if they happen to still have a working interactive session. Since you excluded root, you'll have to hope your user still has a shell running. If so, there should be enough functionality built into their shell to kill off some of the offending processes. You'll need to leverage shell builtins to iterate through `/proc`.

For example, if I wanted to kill off all of my `bash` shells, I could do something like this, which only uses Bash shell builtins:

```
pushd /proc && for pid in *; do
    test "$pid" = "self" && continue        # skip /proc/self
    test -d "$pid" || continue              # skip if not a directory
    test -O "$pid" || continue              # skip if we don't own it
    read cmd < "${pid}/cmdline"
    case "$cmd" in
        *bash*) kill -9 $pid ;;             # or whatever you want to do to it
    esac
done && popd
```

This does suffer from a couple limitations, so it isn't foolproof, but it should be useful in most cases.

1. If there are a ***lot*** of processing running, the `*` expansion at the top of the loop may result in a strings that exceeds the [maximum command length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185017/maximum-number-of-bash-arguments-max-num-cp-arguments). If you run into this, you could pare down the wildcard expansion with multiple runs using `1*`, `2*`, `{1..3}*`, or something like that.
2. `/proc/${pid}/cmdline` contains a NULL-delimited list, of which the actual command is just one item. I'm not aware of a way to cleanly parse such a string using just Bash builtins. Since strings are normally terminated with a NULL, `read` is only going to get the first item, which may or may not be the command name. An alternative approach would be to iterate over `/proc/${pid}/stat` or `/proc/${pid}/status`.